# Hyper-V Woes With Import

Tags: windows-7, backup, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I created a windows 7 virtual, and along the way, exported it to an external hard drive for backup.  HyperV is hosted on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.  I really need to be able to restore the backup, but for 4 of them it says it can't import the virtual hard disk, and the last one begins to import, but I get the data cyclic check error (or whatever it is) and it fails to import.

Why doesn't this work if I exported from hyper V, and do I have any last hope other than to recreate a virtual?

Comment: CRC errors usually relate to data loss, especially in something like a VHD.  Often caused by file-system or drive troubles.  What do "4 of them..and the last one" represent?

Comment: Did you use the export feature? Did you check the box "Export only virtual machine configuration?" I'm assuming you are using Server 2008R2??

Comment: @surfasb I did use the export feature, but there was no "Export only virtual machine configuration?" option present.  I reverified that last night after looking at a tutorial.

Comment: @techie007 I created 5 exports as backups, 4 failed, 1 worked but I got the CRC error.

Comment: To add to this, I would like to say that I examined the files and it exported a VHD, and some it exported a config, but not all.

Comment: Also, I'm using the copy option so that I can essentially duplicate the environment too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would test the VHD file by NOT importing the machine, instead copy the VHD file somewhere safe (on the Server 2008 machine ideally), then create a new virtual machine. When it comes to the part about creating a new hard drive, instead browse for the existing VHD.
See if this new machine will boot up - if not then there is something wrong with the VHD file itself and you probably don't have much hope of recovery.
Good luck with it though!